# How to ignore specific character on Regex.Match

Tags: c#, regex

Hi this is my first question on this forum, as i don't find a solution for this on my own i decided to ask for help

```
string pattern = @"Chapter\s?(.*):\s*(.*)";
var m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
```

I have been using this pattern but not all strings has the same format, i´d like to know if there a way to ignore the ":" character to make it work, or if there a better way to do it

```
//Examples:
"Chapter 3.10:  Some Text"
"Chapter 2.2:  Some Text(2)"
"Chapter 1.20"

//Outputs
"3.10" "Some Text"
"2.2" "Some Text(2)"
"" "" 
// The last return nothing on both groups
// In this case i would like to get only the first group (the chapter number)
```

PS: My english can be poor but thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a pattern which the second group is optional:

```
Chapter\s?([^:]+)(?::\s*(.*))?
```

### Demo

Your updated code:

```
string pattern = @"Chapter\s?([^:]+)(?::\s*(.*))?";
var m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know it was possible